# Initialize Java Components in HTML

Tags: java, html, swing

How do I create/initialize a Java variable in HTML?

I have seen uses of Java in HTML like this:

```
<object classid="javax.swing.JButton" label="I'm a button!"></object>
```

it creates a button that could for instance be displayed in a `JEditorPane`. However, how can I create variables and or initialize those variables/classes with constructors?

I tried for example transforming the:

```
new JLabel(String text);
```

into something like:

```
<object classid="javax.swing.JLabel" value="This is a label!"></object>
```

But no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. The [JavaDoc for ObjectView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/ObjectView.html) has the following example:

```
<object classid="javax.swing.JLabel">
    <param name="text" value="sample text">
</object>
```

You cannot pass parameters to the constructor, but with the `<param name="text" value="sample text">` the code will call `setText("sample text")` on the created `JLabel`